# Discord Bots in Python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I was following a tutorial on making discord bots when I came across a problem.

I'm trying to connect the client to discord using my token, using the code below:

```
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

`
I also have a separate .env file which looks like this:

```
DISCORD_TOKEN="***" ## yeah I'm not giving anyone my token
```

I ran this in the command prompt and I got this error:

```
  File "discordBot.py", line 15, in <module>
    client.run(***)
NameError: name '***' is not defined ## Once again not actually my token
```

The only thing I've noticed is that the name that isn't defined isn't actually the full token and it stops after a ".", I tried putting the entire thing in quotes on the .env file but that didn't fix it.

Comment: Have you tried `load_dotenv(verbose=True)` to ensure your `.env` is loaded correctly?

Answer (score 0):

This is a client side problem. It would be useful if you could post in your question what service you are using to host the bot. It is a problem with either your server or something with your API key. Make sure the key is right. I don't see anything wrong with your program, if you are saving the responses in a file on your computer make sure its in `RB` or `WB` format. Other formats will cause your program to glitch. Best of luck with your bot! This also might be because you are asking the user for an API key and he does not have one. You should switch your `async` data.